# Scala's monadic chaining of Try

Tags: scala, monads, scala-collections

Consider the following chaining of  function `f`, `g` and `h` using monadic for-comprehensions.

```
  for {
    x <- List ( 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 )
    y <- f ( x )
    z <- g ( y )
    a <- h ( z )
  } yield a
```

If `f`, `g` and `h` all have the signature:

```
  Int => Option [ Int ]
```

then for-comprehension compiles fine. However if I replace `Option [ Int ]` by
`Try [ Int ]`, Scala's type-inferencer complains about the line

```
  y <- f ( x )
```

with the following error message.

```
  error: type mismatch;
  found   : scala.util.Try[Int]
  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
      y <- f ( x )
```

Why? Both `Option [ _ ]` and `Try [ _ ]` are (or should be) monads, and should work smoothly as sketched.

Comment: Here is a shorter demo `for { x <- List (1,2,3) ; y <- Some(x)} yield y` is fine whereas `for { x <- List (1,2,3) ; y <- Try{x}} yield y` produces aforementioned error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only use monads of the same kind in a for comprehension. In this case all of your values have to be `GenTraversableOnce`, because the first one is. It works with `Option`, because there is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Seq`, but this is not possible for `Try`.

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to chain my computations monadic style,  but propagate error messages too, what's the recommended Scala way?

Comment: You should take a look at monad transformers. I'd recommend you to use scalaz for that.

Comment: I'm surprise that something conceptually straightforward as chaining monads should require 'heavy equipment'.

Comment: It may be not as simple as you think it is. For example: What should the return type of your example above be? Logically it has to be `List` or some of it's super types. So how does the `Try` fit in? Can you convert a `List` to a `Try`? Or a `Try` to a `List`? For both questions the answer is no (at least if you want to keep all the information).

Comment: You are right. I see now that I do need a monad transformer as I'm trying to use two monads here, `List` and `Try`. I was confused by `Option` working, but I didn't realise that there was an implicit conversion that coerced `Option` into an appropriate sequence monad. I now know exactly how to solve my problem. Thanks for you help.